# Parse the text file, search for the duplicate value and throw error

Tags: java, arrays

below here is my coding logic.

- 1st time user key in Name as "John" and address as "123", save in to
  text file.
- 2nd time user key in exact value Name as "John" and    address as
  "123", it will throw error like "can't be exact value"

I Created text file first

```
            try{

                 new JTextField();
                // create new file
                String path="C:\\export.txt";
                File file = new File(path);

                   // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                   if (!file.exists()) {
                       file.createNewFile();
                   }

                   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                   // write in file                  
                   if (txtName.getText() !=null && txtAddress.getText() !=null)
                   {
                       bw.write(txtName.getText());
                       bw.write(";");
                       bw.write(txtAddress.getText());
                       bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));                          
                       System.out.print("Print Write Line :" +txtName.getText() +txtAddress.getText());

                   }else {                                             
                       System.out.print(""");
                   }                       
                   // close connection
                   bw.flush();
                   bw.close();
                   fw.close();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println(e);
             }
```

Then I created Read file and do checking for duplicated values

```
    try{

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\minzan\\Desktop\\export.txt"));
             String line;

             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 //read all the line from the text file
                 System.out.println("Print Read line :" +line);
             }  

            if((txtName.getText().compareTo(line)==0) && (txtAddress.getText().compareTo(line)==0))
            {
                //read the output line first
                //if o , it is a match and thwor error
                System.out.println("Error : Same Name  and Address :");
            }

            in.close();

             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("Error : Same Name  and Address");
             }
```

This is the output when i type 1st time key in, it straight throw error:

Print Write Line :John123
Print Read line :John;123
Error : Same Name  and Address

Comment: Use a debugger and be particular about the problem. Where exactly is your issue? You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I notice is that in your validation code that checks for duplicate values, you will always compare the input with the very last line in the file.  Also, you are assuming that if an exception is thrown that it means that the name and address are the same.  Since you're not checking to see if the file exists, I am guessing that you're getting a FileNotFoundException that is being thrown when you try to read a file that doesn't exists.  Given that the path in your writer is different than the file in your validation code, I am going to bet that this is it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's read it in english :)

Keep printing the line until line becomes null.

compare name and address to null - NullPointerException!

You probably haven't learn about Set yet but you should at least know about array and for loop. Use those to solve your problem. Use lots of System.out.println() if the program is not doing what you tell it to.